# How can I make a pull request to bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I am trying to create a pull request to a bitbucket repository (somerepo). I have cloned the master from this repository and created a devbranch called mybranch of this locally. I am ready to push this devbranch to somerepo so I can create a pullrequest. When I try to push the devbranch like this:

```
git push --set-upstream origin mybranch
```

I get this error:

```
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://<username>@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo'
```

How can I push mybranch and make a pullrequest to the remote 'somerepo'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to push code to a repository you don't have write access to. That is not the same as making a pull request.

To do that:

1. In the Bitbucket web UI find the project you want to submit a patch to and click **Fork**
2. Push your changes to the fork of the repository under your own account
3. In the web UI find your fork of the project and click **Create pull request**

Comment: Where is the fork button?